# Microchip MCHV reference design Ic Ia IBus current waveforms

Tags: pwm, microchip, inverter, induction-motor

I have built a Microchip MCHV board (ACIM Inverter based driver) from the schematics on the MCHV user manual. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/dsPICDEM%20MCHV%20development%20board%20User%20Guide.pdf) I can run a motor in open loop using AN1206 demo code. I cannot get the closed loop algorithm to work. It depends on analogue signals Ia and Ib.

Attached are DMCI plots of the Ibus Ia Ib and zero crossing signals for a running average of 8 measurements and a plot of the same signals without applying a running average. Also attached are the voltage plots, running a motor with no load.

I don't think they are correct. Does anyone have sample waveforms from an actual MCHV board they can share so I can compare mine or perhaps by looking at my waveforms can comment on what may be wrong.

The peaks seem very small, and seem to be swamped by noise, I have star grounded the DC bus -, agnd and dgnd and have been very careful to separate my ground planes. Does anyone have an idea as to where the noise may be coming from?
I have invested a ton of time into this and really need some help figuring out the problem.

Thanks
[image: waveforms]

Comment: I think you should label what each capture is, its not real clear.

Comment: Pictures of your board wouldn't hurt either.  Of cour$e you could always buy one and compare it?